# Segmentation fault with 42 Minilibx mlx_new_window

Tags: c

I encounter a SegFault by running the very first basics with the minilibx. Has anyone a hint about what am I making wrong?
[image]

Comment: Probably an attempt to dereference a null pointer somewhere. Was `mlx` pointer properly initialized in line 24?

Comment: please don't post code as images!

Comment: To emphasize what @MarcoLucidi said: Here's an excerpt from [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Comment: Duely noted. Thanks. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

According to `mlx_init` [source code](https://github.com/42Paris/minilibx-linux/blob/9cd18136239c50a5dfba4a464ed76eef862fb016/mlx_init.c#L16), it can fail and return null pointer on failure. Most likely subsequent call to `mlx_new_window` tries to use it and crashes. To avoid possible crash, you should add check for null pointer in your code:

```
if (mlx != 0)
{
   // the rest code using mlx variable
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :-) My problem was in my setup : wsl1 instead of wsl2 (sorry for the late answer it took me a while to figure it out!)